# Displace element from its computed position

Tags: positioning, raise

Is there some command to wrap around an element `\unknown{<element>}` that gives a way to place an element, say, 5cm above where it would be placed without the `unknown` wrapper, even if it overlaps something as a result.

Basically, a command that pushes an element 5cm up in any scenario.

My particular use case is that I want to add an x-label to a graph after-the-fact.

Comment: If you tell us how you do your graph we can give more specific solutions. Shifting the position inside a, say, `tikzpicture` can be done using dedicated commands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can raise the text using `\raisebox{<amount>}[<set height>][<set depth>]{<content>}` and also change its official height and depth. The original dimensions are available as `\height`, `\depth`, `\totalheight` (height+depth) and `\width`.

So `\raisebox{5cm}[\height][\depth]{<some content>}` should move it 5cm up, but keep the original dimensions as they are, making LaTeX think the content didn't change.

Comment: What about moving it horizontally? If you wanted to move it 5cm up and then 3cm right/left, what would that be? I tried several combinations but nothing worked.

Comment: @Alenanno: Note that normally you don't move text around like this in a proper document. It's not a website etc. You might want to use a `tikzpicture` instead. Inside normal text you can however use the `adjustbox` package, it give you `\adjustbox{<key=value,...>}{<content>}` with a `raise` key identical to `\raise` and a `lap` key which allows you to move text horizontally. Check the manual for more details. If you have problems feel free to post a new question which links back to this one and includes an example text.

Comment: I actually used the `adjustbox` already, I totally forgot about it... Thank you. By the way, I wasn't moving text but a custom element.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

For the more complex examples, you can use the following:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(0,0) % make a drawing area that takes no place
  \put(5,3){Still, you can put this text 5 cm right and 3 cm above}
  \put(0,0){And another one, placed at the "original point", but occupying no space}
\end{picture}
```

If you want it to occupy its place in horizontal, but to move vertially, you can use

```
\strut% ensures that the line has the correct height
\smash{% smashes its content verically
  \raise 5cm% move the following box 5 cm up
    \hbox{% horizontal contents
      Foo bar}}
```

And you can omit all the `%` and newlines and say just

```
\strut\smash{\raise 5cm\hbox{Foo bar}}
```

Comment: Aren't the last two example different? In one you have the equivalent of `\hbox{ Foo...` and the last one is `\hbox{Foo...` (leading space deleted?).

Comment: Yes, sorry, there should be no space before the percent-sign, corrected.